# Is it normal for my CPU to run at 1GHz higher than base clock speed?

Tags: cpu, desktop-computer, cpu-usage, intel-core-i7, cpu-speed

I have the Intel Core i7-8700 CPU(non K version) and it's constantly running at much  hicher clock speeds than it's base speed and I was wondering if that's normal?

[image]

Comment: Yes, perfectly normal: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/126686/intel-core-i7-8700-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html

Comment: Not all CPUs are built the same. For example some CPUs are capable of much better overclock speeds than others.

Comment: @Sickest With a maximum frequency of 4.60 GHz we're perfectly within specs, no OC involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's actually a feature called [Turbo Boost](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html). According to the official intel documentation the [i7-8700](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/126686/intel-core-i7-8700-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html) (non-K) has a max turbo boost of 4.6GHz so you're well within spec.

For extra info: How much your CPU boosts depends on many factors like utilization, power delivery (do you have a good PSU?), and cooling solution.